# How to format a decimal in python with variable number of decimals

Tags: python, python-3.x

To format the number `20` as `20.00` I can do:

```
'%.2f' % 20.283928
'20.28'
```

However, I want to allow the user to be able to specify the number of decimal places. For example:

```
value = 20.283928
num_decimal_places = 7 # from user input
'%.%sf' % (20, '7')
```

How could I do something like the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If version of python greater or equals to 3.6:

```
print(f'%.{num_decimal_places}f'%value)
```

Output:

```
20.2839280
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use newer `format` you can do this:

```
>>> n = 4
>>> value = 20.283928
>>> '{:.{count}f}'.format(value, count=n)

'20.2839'
```